# Selecting full table when formatting date

Tags: sql

I am a complete beginner with SQL and I have been struggling with this for a while now and can't seem to come to the correct answer by myself.

I am using the following code to display Date_t in the correct format

```
select date_format(Date_t, '%d/%m/%y at %k:%i') 
as formatted_date 
from tests
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I can now display Date_t formatted as formatted_date but for the life of me cannot work out how to display the rest of my columns from tests.

Apologies if this is a really stupid question.

Comment: "rest of my data" what data? please edit the question and provide complete details. tag question with appropriate database platform.  read [ask].  thanks

Comment: Apologies @OldProgrammer, "rest of my data" was poorly written, I am looking to for the remaining columns from tests. 

SELECT * FROM `tests` would work, but then I wouldn't have date_t formatted.

Comment: You have to list them individually, separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00 got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Yust put the other columns koma separeted before or after your formating string. Like SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table